# JCE maybe stripping my html code

Tags: joomla

I have a problem with my JCE and Joomla installation.

**The problem**

- Whenever I am writing HTML code in the editor it keeps stripping the code when I save the article.
- If I change the editor to the default one the HTML code stays?!

**What I have tried**

- I have tried to change the text filter in global settings to no filtering but that didn't solve it.
- I did also try to enable java script and disable HTML validation in the JCE profile editor, didn't work ether.

I am using Joomla 2.5.7 and JCE 2.2.8.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What kind of html code it is stripping? Not the `p` or `h` tags of course ?
Are you trying to put any iframes ?

JCE Editor has special settings for what it will be allowed. 
Go in JCE Editor Profiles -> Plug-in Parameters -> Media Support and make sure you have the desired settings enabled.

All these, alongside with the standard Joomla filtering.

Comment: For example the iframe when I want to add a youtube video

Comment: thanks that was it :D... just couldn't locate where to change it ;)